# Revoke and grant permissions from one user to another

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have 3 users `A`, `B` & `C`. I have granted privileges on `A.TABLE1` to `B` and, from B, privileges on `A.TABLE1` to `C`.

I want to revoke the privileges from user `B` using user `A` but keep it for `C`. How would I go about this?

Comment: Please post some code and show us what you tried.

Comment: This is what i tried..Create user A identified by a;
Create user B identified by b;
Create user C identified by c;
(Then assigned all the privileges to create table and connect)
Now,
Conn A/a
Create table tb1(id number);
Grant all on tb1 to B with grant option
Conn B/b
Grant all on tb1 to C
Conn A/a
Revoke all on tb1 from B
Conn C/c
Select * from a.tb1;
(And I get insufficient privileges)
I want to keep this privileges for C

Answer (score 0):

You have `A -> B -> C` and you want `A -> C`. So, just do that. Grant privileges directly on `A.TABLE1` to `C` and then revoke privileges on `A.TABLE1` from `B`.

If you were granting SELECT then, when connected to user `A`, run:

```
grant select on table1 to c;
revoke select on table1 from b;
```

Comment: Actually i have assigned a task to do in my college that i have granted A->B and then B->C now wanted to revoke the rights from B but should not be revoked from C.